# Missing command palate dnu in visual studio code for windows

Tags: visual-studio-code

How to debug in visual studio code without dnu . run?
My dnu missing in visual studio for windows.
i tried to use in command promp, it working fine. but not in visual studio code.

Comment: This might be a bug, feel free to file here with reproducable steps https://code.visualstudio.com/Issues/List

Answer (score 0):

Having same issue none of the dnx commands are showing up in Visual Studio code.

"commands": {
    "kestrel": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel --config hosting.ini",
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener --config hosting.ini",
    "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
  },

Also in status it does not show "1 Project"

as in screenshot here:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-app-using-vscode/

Comment: Not a question but issue :)

Answer (score 0):

(Just re-read the OP and realised it was about Code on Windows, here is my answer if anyone has this problem on OSX/Yosemite)

I had this problem as well and found I needed to upgrade mono (from 3.1? to 4.2) and run dnu restore.

```
brew uninstall mono
brew update
brew install -g mono
cd /my/project/
dnu restore
```

Check your bash profile file ~/.bash_profile as well, mine looks like this:

```
export PATH="~/npm-global/bin:$PATH"
source /Users/andrew/.dnx/dnvm/dnvm.sh
code () { VSCODE_CWD="$PWD" open -n -b "com.microsoft.VSCode" --args $* ;}
export MONO_GAC_PREFIX="/usr/local"
```

Then quit and re-open code. Mine didn't pick it up straight away, so try opening your project.json or another file and making a small change to see if that kicks it into gear.

Answer (score -1):

Can you post what's in your `project.json` file? It should contain a commands section like so

`...
"commands": {
    "ConsoleApp": "run"
},
...`

Comment: I don't think whats in your project files commands section has anything to do with dnx. I commented out my entire commands section and still had dnx available.